# Show a download list with qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

What is the best way to show a list of downloads using QT4?

1 QListWidget

2 QTreeWidget

3 QTableWidget

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much functionality you want.  If you just want to simply list the filenames, use a `QListWidget`.  If you want to list other things like progress, filesize, etc. then you may want to use a `QTableWidget`.  If you want to be able to group downloads under different categories, you can use the `QTreeWidget`, which will also allow for multiple table cells per row like the `QTableWidget`.

If you want something fancier like the firefox downloader, you may have to create an item delegate to handle the drawing yourself.

Comment: I would make use of a QTableWidget and probably a custom widget for a download bar to be used in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [model-view-controller](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/model-view-programming.html) widgets.

```
QListView
QTableView
QTreeView
```